# What did Fraçois la Rouchefoucauld mean by "gravity is a mysterious carriage of the body"

Tags: interpretation

There is this famous quote from the french writer, which goes like

> Gravity is a mysterious carriage of the body invented to conceal the want of mind

I don't quite understand what the word gravity means here (is it the physics one or just like seriousness or even how much we weigh certain topics) and what is the sense of this sentence, is this a form of subjectivism?

Comment: gravité = seriousness

Comment: @JoWehler the same word is used in physics tho https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loi_universelle_de_la_gravitation

Comment: i'd have thought it's a play on words. what's the point of the question? you like the phrase or agree with it?

Comment: Gravity belongs to the material while the want of mind is that which is spiritual…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before Newton, 'gravity' was variously used to mean weight, mass, seriousness, ponderousness, and the opposite of 'levity'. There was a cartoon in 1763 by Hogarth called 'The Weighing House' - I can't find a royalty-free version of this but a search should turn it up - showing nine degrees between 'gravity' and 'levity'.

A better translation these days might use 'gravitas' rather than 'gravity'. This is the mysterious bearing that makes some people appear profound, respectable, and trustworthy; and which can work as substitute for ability in society.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speculate about historical context, but the meaning in the original French seems obvious to me. From [Réflexions](https://books.google.com/books?id=QSdPNfXQavAC&oe=UTF-8), a book of collected maxims - so it's probably not even the author's own words, and there's no textual context to put it in. Page 71, page 103 of the digitization.

«La gravité est un mystère du corps, inventé pour cacher les défauts de l'esprit.»

Transliterated:

"Gravitas is a mystery of the body, invented for to hide defects of the mind."

The main sense of *hide* in *cacher* is to conceal by putting something in a place where it cannot easily be seen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't speak French, and I think you should ask on that stackexchange really

> Gravity is a mysterious carriage of the body invented to conceal the
> want of mind

Is it the case that seriousness is for stupid people? I don't think it's great psychologically or philosophically, and the claim should probably be contextualised in 17th century France if you want to assess its truth rather than marvel at the language.